# Access/ SQL query for movements when only one date per condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to do a query via either **SQL or Access** to track patient movements, but really struggling. The problem I am up against is that there is only one location per patient per day, but patients can move back between wards, therefore trying to use patient/location and max and min date is not sufficient.

Example:

```
 - RowID: 1 Patient A - Ward 10 - 01/01/2015  
 - RowID: 2 Patient A - Ward 10 - 02/01/2015
 - RowID: 3 Patient A - Ward 11 - 03/01/2015  
 - RowID: 4 Patient A - Ward 10 - 04/01/2015
 - RowID: 5 Patient B - Ward 11 - 01/01/2015
```

As you can see, the location is only captured, once a day, but I want to develop a movement, and using my `max date` if `grouped by patient and ward` would give a last date on Ward 10 of 04/01/2015, which is technically correct, but I want to capture the movement on the 02/01/2015. I want to be able to show the following for example:

```
 - Patient A - Ward 10 01/01/2015 - 02/01/2015
 - Patient A - Ward 11 03/01/2015 - 03/01/2015
 - Patient A - Ward 10 04/01/2015 -
 - Patient B - Ward 11 01/01/2015 -
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Kind regards,
Sie

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "SQL" you mean Microsoft SQL Server, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup a `Self Join` with same Table and align the rows using conditions so that they line up next to each other

Setup:

```
SELECT * INTO #TABLE FROM 
(
SELECT 1 ROWID, 'Patient A' PAT , 'Ward 10' loc ,'01/01/2015' recorddate UNION ALL
select 2 ROWID, 'Patient A' PAT , 'Ward 10' loc ,'02/01/2015' recorddate UNION ALL
select 3 ROWID, 'Patient A' PAT , 'Ward 11' loc ,'03/01/2015' recorddate  UNION ALL
select 4 ROWID, 'Patient A' PAT , 'Ward 10' loc ,'04/01/2015' recorddate UNION ALL
select 5 ROWID, 'Patient B' PAT , 'Ward 11' loc ,'01/01/2015' recorddate) A
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
A.pat, A.loc, a.recorddate, MIN(b.recorddate) 
FROM #table A
INNER JOIN #TABLE B
ON A.PAT=B.pat
and (A.recorddate<B.recorddate)
group by A.ROWID, A.pat, A.loc, a.recorddate

UNION ALL 
-- Get the row that donot have a To Date

SELECT A.PAT, LOC , A.recorddate, NULL
FROM #table A
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
B.pat, MAX(B.recorddate) recorddate
FROM #table B
GROUP BY B.PAT) B
on A.PAT=B.PAT
and A.recorddate=B.recorddate
```

Result:

```
pat         loc     FROMDATE    TODATE
Patient A   Ward 10 01/01/2015  02/01/2015
Patient A   Ward 10 02/01/2015  03/01/2015
Patient A   Ward 11 03/01/2015  04/01/2015
Patient B   Ward 11 01/01/2015  NULL
Patient A   Ward 10 04/01/2015  NULL
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, however, it works exactly as you described, however (and I suspect the problem lies in my description) I don't want a row for every single date. For example, patient A is in Ward 10 on 01/01/2015, 02/01/2015, 03/01/2015, 04/01/2015, then in Ward 11 on 05/01/2015 and 06/01/2015 then back in ward 10 on 07/01/2015... I would like my results to show these grouped, i.e. Patient A, Ward 10 From 01/01/2015 - 04/01/2015, Patient A, Ward 11 From 05/01/2015 - 06/01/2015 then Patient A, Ward 10 From 07/01/2015. Hope this makes sense?